# MUI Change css of Label of Select and color of selected option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, mui

I am struggling with **MUI** components few days, building a page in a React app.

I'm almost done, just 2 things missing...

I am using a **Select** and an **Autocomplete** in my page. 
In both of them I set
`{shrink=false}`
 to the input label, but I don't know how to apply `display:none` **once an option is selected** (like instead of shrinking just disappear - now they overlap on top of each other - I don't know why it's not like this by default when shrink is set to false...).

Also, in the select component, I need the **colour of the selected option** to be white when it's inside the input text (instead of the label - now, together with it... - now it's black).

Is anyone able to help me?
Or at least pointing me a direction where to look at?

I'm going through the documentation, but I am not able to figure out a way. Should I do something when the handleChange method is called? - That is the moment... but then, how to change their style?

Thanks to anyone who can help 
xxx

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using the state:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
```

In the `<Select>` component:

```
onChange={(event) => {
  setSelected(true);
  handleChange(event);
}}
```

And then I set the input label value to be either a string OR the selected option:

```
<InputLabel
  ref={inputLabel}
  className={classes.inputLabel}
  id="simple-select-label"
  shrink={false}
>
  {selected ? '' : 'Itinerario'}
</InputLabel>
```

Hope to help someone.
x